# How to launch PhpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench for an AWS Ec2 WordPress instance?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I launched a WordPress instance in EC2 in AWS. Now I can access WordPress Dashboard. But how to access database? If I install WordPress in my PC I can easily access it via a local-host link. From AWS how can I access the same? Also, is there any possibility to connect the MySQL database via MySQL Workbench?

Thanks
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

Venkata, you are able to access WordPress hosted on EC2 because the http port and https port is open in the firewall, check your inbound settings in security group.

You can access your MySQL Database hosted in same EC2 instance (in this specific case) if you can open the port for access, in inbound settings. Make sure you have a MySQL user created and you have user name and password for the user.

Answer (score 0):

First On EC2 instance you have to configure complete LAMP stack and than you have to open the port from security groups from AWS console admin. 
After installing LAMP stack and opening port you have to place adminer.php file on the /var/www/html directory or the directory where you installed the wordpress.
after that you can access the database and the wordpress